# How to float image in the middle?

Tags: css

I'm setting up a new business blog and I'm having troubles getting the main logo to be centered in the middle of the header.

I know you can use:

```
#logo { float: left; }
#logo { float: right; }
```

But from what I can see floating in the middle isn't an available option.

Any suggestions?

Site I'm having problems with: http://bit.ly/Yrcm5z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following css on your `#logo img`

```
#logo img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your `img` is displayed as a `block` element, and, as such, giving a margin value of `auto` tells the browser to calculate the available margin inside the parent element and share it equally on both sides of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div>
    <a id="logo"></a>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#logo {display: inline-block; }

div {text-align: center; }
```

Sory, and for the record, this method works because `display: inline-block;` elements behave as text, so you can align the as it inside a container.

Greeting from Argentina!

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align in new a **paragraph** or **div**.

```
<p><img src="http://legendarymarketer.com/wp-content/themes/wp-theme-simplog/assets/img/logo.png" height="30" width="235" alt="" style="
    text-align: center;
"></p>
```

Change the CSS: [**Line 104** of **style.css** file]

```
#logo img {
display: inline;
}
```